# Что такое диапазон ip адресов?

Tags: ip, ip-address

Искал информацию по этому в интернете, но я все равно плохо понимаю какие адреса входят в диапазон. Например диапазон `192.168.1.1 - 192.168.3.3`, если грубо перечислить туда входят такие адреса:

`192.168.1.1
...
198.168.1.255
192.168.2.1
...
192.168.2.255
192.168.3.1
...
192.168.3.3`

или

`192.168.1.1
...
192.168.1.3
192.168.2.1
...
192.168.2.3
192.168.3.1
...
192.168.3.3`

?
Если есть понятная статья или описание, помогите, пожалуйста

Comment: Первый вариант верный, но зависит еще от маски

Comment: @Node_pro Когда идёт речь о диапазоне - какая маска? это же не подсеть, это тупо "от и до"...

Answer (score 1):

Первый вариант более логичен. Потому что ip это просто число из 4х байт, каждая из цифр значение отдельного байта. Тогда 192.168.1.1 это 0xC0A80101 (3232235777 в десятичной системе). Отбросим старшие 2 байта для простоты 0x0101 = 257 (дес) 0x0303 = 771. Диапазон чисел целых от 257 до 771 по обычным представлениям включает все числа, больше 257 и меньшие 771. Тогда например 1.255 = 0x01FF = 511 явно в него входит.

Во втором же случае выходит, что число 511 должно быть вне диапазона 257-771, что с точки зрения понятия "диапазон" не верно.